# How to refresh Hubspot oauth access token using Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, hubspot, hubspot-api

Using the Hubspot Ruby get, 16.4.0: https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-ruby/tree/v16.4.0

We can oauth successfully, but can't refresh token:

```
client = ::Hubspot::Client.new(access_token:  '{oauth-access-token}')
client.o_auth.refresh_tokens_api.get_refresh_token

LoadError: cannot load such file -- hubspot/codegen/oauth/models/token
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks simply broken (https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-ruby/blob/master/lib/hubspot/discovery/base_api_client.rb#L156). It's requiring "hubspot/codegen/o_auth/models/token" which is nowhere in the code. You might want to handle the refresh request yourself.